# Sharepoint 2010 Foundation Authentication with Office 365

Tags: sharepoint, authentication, sharepoint-2010, amazon-web-services, windows-live-id

I have SharePoint 2010 foundation installed on a AWS (Amazaon Web Services) server. I also have office365 (Email Hosted Plan Accounts). Is it possible to link to office 365 for authentication when a user tries to access the SharePoint site? In other words, can I use Office365 as authentication provider similar to windows live id with in share point.

Any pointers will help.